# Is there a specific convention when passing multiple arguments into a function?

Tags: python, function, arguments, conventions

I'm just starting out on Python and creating a main function in python which receives 4 arguments. Then within that function, another two functions are called which require the same 4 arguments.

Which below is more "Pythonic"?

A)

```
def function_main(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    innner_function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
    second_inner_function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

B)

```
def function_main(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4):
    arg_list = [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
    innner_function(arg_list)
    second_inner_function(arg_list)
```

The second seems more DRY, but I'm not sure whether it's too DRY if there's such a thing. Which would be considered the best to use?

Comment: Just to note: A & B aren't identical... you'd need to unpack `arg_list` for them to be so - eg: `inner_function(*arg_list)`

Comment: You should be able to use `*args` in both the `def function_main` and all the calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is rather a question of design than "style" conventions and I would advise avoiding both. Additionally, even for illustration purposes, please don't do "working pseudo code" with naming like "function_*" or similar.

According to the question, let's zoom out a little for a broader view. Consider some aspects (keep in mind OOP practices):
• a main method (or definition in Python) is basically existing for structural purposes and readability
• an array of identical primitives should, most likely, not be passed as separate elements, however:
• if you need these values separate, keep them like this for nested functionality
• if you don't, assign them before a to a variable, an object, to enums or constants even (be careful, think about design)
• if your elements are different data types of rather unrelated content, keep them separate as well
• if they are different, but should be kept together for contextual reasons think about creating a class and work with an object
• if your elements are a subset of greater data retention, think of using appropriate data structures like XML, JSON or even a database and design in appropriate OO
• (there is always something you miss at design, get used to it, never stop reflecting)

My suggestion would be to simply go on practicing. This is a question existing only at beginner level and will fade quickly with your growing design experience.